# Knockout: How to pass data-bound input value back to function on click?

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js, data-binding, click

I have a simple checkbox. It gets its own `value` attribute from the view model. On click, I need to send that value back to a function. How do I do that?

I tried this but value did not work

```
<input class="cards-view--item-checkbox pull-right" type="checkbox" 
data-bind="value: universalParcelId, click: $root.addUniversalParcelIDtoArray(value)" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to the `click` binding is a function that it will run for that event. It's not an expression. If you're using  http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/, you could use the `on.click` binding to supply an expression. Also, to get the property of the element, use `$element`.

Here's how you'd supply a function:

```
click: function(data, event) { $root.handleClick($element.value, data, event) }
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks. However I couldn't get additional parameters like `$data` or `$event` to pass through using the function wrapper.

Comment: Excellent. That works. I'm accepting your answer. I'm also trying to pass whether the input is checked or not by sending parameter of "true/false". Is there an easy way to do that also?

Comment: I got it. $element.checked passes the state of the checkbox! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty well covered in the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) for the click binding.  There are really multiple ways this can be handled.  Whenever you use the click binding is passes the data from the context to "this" in the function.  So, most likely you don't need to pass anything at all if "value" is a property on the model in your current context.  (See note 1 in the documentation)

```
var rootModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.addUniversalParcelIDtoArray = function() {
       console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

However, you may need to pass something else besides data in your current context.  In that case, you can use the .bind function that will add the additional parameters.  The $data still passes the model from the current context to "this" in addition to the value property from the $parent context.  (See note 2 in the documentation)

```
<input class="cards-view--item-checkbox pull-right" type="checkbox" 
data-bind="value: universalParcelId, click: $root.addUniversalParcelIDtoArray.bind($data, $parent.value)" />
```

Comment: `$data` came through "undefined" and `$parent.value` came through with what `$data` normally brings. Something didn't work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I had to do it a little different to get the value to pass through with the $data and $event objects plus custom parameters. I pulled the value out using `event.target.value`

I ended up using:

`click: function(data, event) { $root.addUniversalParcelIDtoArray(data, event, 'param1', 'param2') }`

Here's the addUniversalParcelIDtoArray function:

```
addUniversalParcelIDtoArray: function (data, event, 'param1', 'param2') {
    var self = monsoon.Search;
    self.universalParcelIDArray.push(event.target.value);
    return true; // allow the default "click" action, which is checking the box with a "check"
},
```